# Can't deserialize JSON into an object with nested list

Tags: c#, json, firebase, deserialization, fire-sharp

Apologies for asking a fairly common question, I have been looking all over and can't find a solution that fixes my problem.

I am using Firesharp, and trying to deserialize a Json object that Firebase returns into a class with a nested list.

```
public class Class
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Desc { get; set; }
        public string HPDie { get; set; }
        public string Role { get; set; }
        public int RPL { get; set; }
        public IList<Level> Levels { get; set; }

        public Class() { }
        public Class(string name, string desc, string hpdie, string role, int rPL, List<Level> levels) 
        {
            Name = name;
            Desc = desc;
            HPDie = hpdie;
            RPL = rPL;
            Levels = levels;
        }
    }
```

As you can see it has a list of Levels, another class with the following code:

```
public class Level
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public int BAB { get; set; }
        public int FortSave { get; set; }
        public int WillSave { get; set; }
        public int RexSave { get; set; }
        public int SpellsKnown { get; set; }
        public List<Skill> Skills { get; set; }

        public Level() { }
        public Level(int number, int bab, int cmb, int cmd, int fortsave, int willsave, int rexsave, List<Skill> skills)
        {
            Number = number;
            BAB = bab;
            FortSave = fortsave;
            WillSave = willsave;
            RexSave = rexsave;
            Skills = skills;
        }

        public class LevelList
        {
            List<Level> levellist { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

That at the same time, has a list of Skills. The Skill class only has two strings, a name and a description.

The code I'm using to deserialize is:

```
private async void RefreshClasses()
    {
        this.classList = new List<Class>();
        FirebaseResponse res = await client.GetAsync("Class");

        IEnumerable<Class> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Class>>(res.Body);

        if (data != null)
        {
            PopulateDGVClasses(data);
        }
    }
```

But when it gets to the Deserialization it returns the following error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the
> current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[CaminanteHelper.Class]'
> because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
> correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array
> (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal
> .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection
> type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON
> object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it
> to deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'Barbarian', line 1, position
> 13.'

Again, I think I should be able to fix this by myself, but I've been stuck for almost two days already.

Thank you all in advance!

Edit: Json that I'm trying to deserialize:

```
    {
  "Class" : {
    "Barbarian" : {
      "Desc" : "Barbarians excel in combat, possessing the martial prowess and fortitude to take on foes seemingly far superior to themselves. With rage granting them boldness and daring beyond that of most other warriors, barbarians charge furiously into battle and ruin all who would stand in their way.",
      "HPDie" : "d12",
      "Levels" : [ {
        "BAB" : 2,
        "FortSave" : 2,
        "Number" : 1,
        "RexSave" : 0,
        "Skills" : {
          "Prueba" : {
            "Desc" : "Probota"
          }
        },
        "SpellsKnown" : 0,
        "WillSave" : 0
      }, {
        "BAB" : 3,
        "FortSave" : 3,
        "Number" : 2,
        "RexSave" : 0,
        "SpellsKnown" : 0,
        "WillSave" : 0
      }, {
        "BAB" : 3,
        "FortSave" : 3,
        "Number" : 3,
        "RexSave" : 1,
        "SpellsKnown" : 0,
        "WillSave" : 1
      }, {
        "BAB" : 4,
        "FortSave" : 4,
        "Number" : 4,
        "RexSave" : 1,
        "SpellsKnown" : 0,
        "WillSave" : 1
      }, {
        "BAB" : 5,
        "FortSave" : 4,
        "Number" : 5,
        "RexSave" : 1,
        "SpellsKnown" : 0,
        "WillSave" : 1
      }, {
        "BAB" : 6,
        "FortSave" : 5,
        "Number" : 6,
        "RexSave" : 2,
        "SpellsKnown" : 0,
        "WillSave" : 2
      }, {
        "BAB" : 7,
        "FortSave" : 5,
        "Number" : 7,
        "RexSave" : 2,
        "SpellsKnown" : 0,
        "WillSave" : 2
      }, {
        "BAB" : 8,
        "FortSave" : 6,
        "Number" : 8,
        "RexSave" : 2,
        "SpellsKnown" : 0,
        "WillSave" : 2
      }, {
        "BAB" : 9,
        "FortSave" : 6,
        "Number" : 9,
        "RexSave" : 3,
        "SpellsKnown" : 0,
        "WillSave" : 3
      }, {
        "BAB" : 10,
        "FortSave" : 7,
        "Number" : 10,
        "RexSave" : 3,
        "SpellsKnown" : 0,
        "WillSave" : 3
      } ],
      "Name" : "Barbarian",
      "RPL" : 4
    },
    "Wizard" : {
      "Desc" : "While universalist wizards might study to prepare themselves for any manner of danger, specialist wizards research schools of magic that make them exceptionally skilled within a specific focus. \r\n\r\nYet no matter their specialty, all wizards are masters of the impossible and can aid their allies in overcoming any danger.",
      "HPDie" : "d6",
      "Levels" : [ {
        "BAB" : 0,
        "FortSave" : 0,
        "Number" : 1,
        "RexSave" : 0,
        "SpellsKnown" : 4,
        "WillSave" : 2
      }, {
        "BAB" : 1,
        "FortSave" : 0,
        "Number" : 2,
        "RexSave" : 0,
        "SpellsKnown" : 6,
        "WillSave" : 3
      }, {
        "BAB" : 1,
        "FortSave" : 1,
        "Number" : 3,
        "RexSave" : 1,
        "SpellsKnown" : 7,
        "WillSave" : 3
      }, {
        "BAB" : 2,
        "FortSave" : 1,
        "Number" : 4,
        "RexSave" : 1,
        "SpellsKnown" : 9,
        "WillSave" : 4
      }, {
        "BAB" : 2,
        "FortSave" : 1,
        "Number" : 5,
        "RexSave" : 1,
        "SpellsKnown" : 10,
        "WillSave" : 4
      }, {
        "BAB" : 3,
        "FortSave" : 2,
        "Number" : 6,
        "RexSave" : 2,
        "SpellsKnown" : 12,
        "WillSave" : 5
      }, {
        "BAB" : 3,
        "FortSave" : 2,
        "Number" : 7,
        "RexSave" : 2,
        "SpellsKnown" : 14,
        "WillSave" : 5
      }, {
        "BAB" : 4,
        "FortSave" : 2,
        "Number" : 8,
        "RexSave" : 2,
        "SpellsKnown" : 16,
        "WillSave" : 6
      }, {
        "BAB" : 4,
        "FortSave" : 3,
        "Number" : 9,
        "RexSave" : 3,
        "SpellsKnown" : 18,
        "WillSave" : 6
      }, {
        "BAB" : 5,
        "FortSave" : 3,
        "Number" : 10,
        "RexSave" : 3,
        "SpellsKnown" : 20,
        "WillSave" : 7
      } ],
      "Name" : "Wizard",
      "RPL" : 2
    }
  },
  "Equipment" : {
    "Battleaxe" : {
      "ACBonus" : 0,
      "ACType" : "(None)",
      "Blunt" : false,
      "Bonus" : "",
      "Category" : "Weapon",
      "Cost" : "10gp",
      "DMG_Large" : "1d10",
      "DMG_Medium" : "1d8",
      "DMG_Small" : "1d6",
      "Description" : "The handle of this axe is long enough that you can wield it one-handed or two-handed. The head may have one blade or two, with blade shapes ranging from half-moons to squared edges like narrower versions of woodcutting axes. The wooden haft may be protected and strengthened with metal bands called langets.",
      "Name" : "Battleaxe",
      "Penetrating" : false,
      "Range" : "",
      "Slashing" : true,
      "Throwable" : false
    },
    "Composite Longbow" : {
      "ACBonus" : 0,
      "ACType" : "(None)",
      "Blunt" : false,
      "Bonus" : "If your STR is equal or more than the rating, add your STR bonus to damage made with this weapon.",
      "Category" : "Weapon",
      "Cost" : "100gp",
      "DMG_Large" : "1d10",
      "DMG_Medium" : "1d8",
      "DMG_Small" : "1d6",
      "Description" : "You need at least two hands to use a bow, regardless of its size. You can use a composite longbow while mounted.",
      "Name" : "Composite Longbow",
      "Penetrating" : true,
      "Range" : "110ft",
      "Slashing" : false,
      "Throwable" : false
    },
    "Dagger" : {
      "ACBonus" : 0,
      "ACType" : "(None)",
      "Blunt" : false,
      "Bonus" : "+2 to Steal rolls made to hide this weapon.",
      "Category" : "Weapon",
      "Cost" : "6gp",
      "DMG_Large" : "1d6",
      "DMG_Medium" : "1d4",
      "DMG_Small" : "1d3",
      "Description" : "A one handed broad blade, shorter than a shortsword yet longer than a knife.",
      "Name" : "Dagger",
      "Penetrating" : true,
      "Range" : "10ft",
      "Slashing" : true,
      "Throwable" : true
    },
    "Shield" : {
      "ACBonus" : 2,
      "ACType" : "Light",
      "Blunt" : true,
      "Bonus" : "",
      "Category" : "Armor",
      "Cost" : "12gp",
      "DMG_Large" : "1d6",
      "DMG_Medium" : "1d4",
      "DMG_Small" : "1d2",
      "Description" : "Made of leather.",
      "Name" : "Shield",
      "Penetrating" : false,
      "Range" : "",
      "Slashing" : false,
      "Throwable" : false
    },
    "Sword" : {
      "ACBonus" : 0,
      "ACType" : "(None)",
      "Blunt" : false,
      "Bonus" : "",
      "Category" : "Weapon",
      "Cost" : "15gp",
      "DMG_Large" : "1d10",
      "DMG_Medium" : "1d8",
      "DMG_Small" : "1d6",
      "Description" : "This sword is about three and a half feet in length.",
      "Name" : "Sword",
      "Penetrating" : false,
      "Range" : "",
      "Slashing" : true,
      "Throwable" : false
    }
  },
  "Feat" : {
    "Acrobatic" : {
      "Desc" : "+2 to all of your Acrobatic rolls per each five character levels.",
      "Name" : "Acrobatic",
      "PreReq" : [ "" ],
      "Type" : "General"
    },
    "Agile Maiden" : {
      "Desc" : "For the purpose of class features (such as a ranger’s combat style, a barbarian’s fast movement, or a magus’s spellcasting), you treat Gray Maiden plate as medium armor or heavy armor, whichever is more beneficial to a given ability. This does not affect the armor’s statistics, and it is still considered heavy armor for all other purposes",
      "Name" : "Agile Maiden",
      "PreReq" : [ "Str 13", "Dex 13" ],
      "Type" : "Combat"
    }
  },
  "Spell" : {
    "Cure Minor Wounds" : {
      "CastingTime" : "None.",
      "Desc" : "When laying your hand upon a living creature, you channel positive energy that cures 1d8 points of damage +1 point per caster level (maximum +5). Since undead are powered by negative energy, this spell deals damage to them instead of curing their wounds. An undead creature can apply Spell Resistance, and can attempt a Will save to take half damage.",
      "Duration" : "Instantaneous.",
      "FortRes" : false,
      "Name" : "Cure Minor Wounds",
      "PreReq" : [ "1 Divine" ],
      "RexRes" : false,
      "School" : "Conjuration",
      "Target" : "Touched Creature.",
      "WillRes" : true
    },
    "Magic Missile" : {
      "CastingTime" : "None.",
      "Desc" : "A missile of magical energy darts forth from your fingertip and strikes its target, dealing 1d4+1 points of force damage.\r\n\r\nThe missile strikes unerringly, even if the target is in melee combat, so long as it has less than total cover or total concealment. Specific parts of a creature can’t be singled out. Objects are not damaged by the spell.\r\n\r\nFor every two caster levels beyond 1st, you gain an additional missile – two at 3rd level, three at 5th, four at 7th, and the maximum of five missiles at 9th level or higher. If you shoot multiple missiles, you can have them strike a single creature or several creatures. A single missile can strike only one creature. You must designate targets before you check for spell resistance or roll damage.",
      "Duration" : "Instantaneous.",
      "FortRes" : false,
      "Name" : "Magic Missile",
      "PreReq" : [ "1 Divine\r\n1 Arcane\r\n1 Divine\r\n1 Arcane\r\n1 Divine\r\n1 Arcane\r\n" ],
      "RexRes" : false,
      "School" : "Evocation",
      "Target" : "Up to five none of which can be separated by more than 15 ft.",
      "WillRes" : false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It really helps if you also add the json you're trying to deserialize, so anything I say is based on assumptions about the unprovided json. That said it looks like a common mistake. You ask it to deserialize an `IEnumerable` (so a json array starting with `[` and ending with `]` and you've probably provided it with a single instance (staring with `{` and ending with `}`). So either fix the json (just add `[]` around whatever you have now) or change the deserialization to this `Class data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class>(res.Body);`.

Comment: Apologies, Json added. Both solutions provided, adding [ ] to turn the classes into an array nor the change in code seemed to fix the problem.

Comment: Your class structures are completely wrong for the json. `Class` does not have name, description , hpdie, etc,. Barbarian and Wizard do. You may want to use a tool like visual studio's paste json as classes to automatically generate your classes and then you can modify them as needed.

Comment: I'm afraid I do not understand, sorry. What I am trying to do is I fill out a form with the details of a class, and then it gets uploaded to the Firebase, refreshing a list inside the program where I can select the name of a class to have it's details fill the form, included another two lists for levels and skills respectively.


If I do I would not be able to add new classes, right? Since I would need to create a new Class inside the code too.

Comment: First of all my original comment was correct, however since there are more problem it still not works after the fix (Keep in mind though it fixes the described problem, it's just that a new problem pops up, my assumption would be you receive a slightly different exception message). As @Crowcoder said, your models don't fit your json. In your json your `Class` contains 2 properties: `Barbarian` and `Wizard`. This structure is not reflected in your models so it can't convert. Try a tool like https://json2csharp.com/ to see how your json is structured.

Comment: You might want the `Class` property to be a `Dictionary<string, Class`, but then you need a root object to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This in no way a complete answer. I assume you don't want to map/create classes for each "sub class", e.g. Barbarian, Wizard etc. You could perhaps use JsonConverter. The example only handles the first "anonymous" range of objects. Maybe you'll find some of this useful.

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(jsonInput);
```

```
public class ClassJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return new Class
        {
            ClassSpecifics = JObject.Load(reader).Values().Select(x => x.ToObject<ClassSpecifics>()).ToList()
        };
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }   
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}

public class Response
{
    public Class Class { get; set; }
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(ClassJsonConverter))]
public class Class
{
    public List<ClassSpecifics> ClassSpecifics { get; set; }
}

public class ClassSpecifics
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public string HPDie { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public int RPL { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you very much.